# Blob based 'link stylesheet' vs standard 'style' tag

Tags: javascript, css, http, blob

I wonder what is the benefit and difference when using styles as Blob links:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="blob:http://www.domain.com/hash-here">
```

over the standard tag:

```
<style>...</style>
```

I mean Blob creation like:

```
var blob = new Blob([css_here], {type: 'text/css'});
var link = document.createElement('link');
link.rel = 'stylesheet';
link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
head.appendChild(link);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

- Memory management

If you put stuff as `style`, and then remove - it's gone.
However, if you put stuff as blob url and then remove - you still have the blob url stored in memory, and it should be released manually.
See the notes here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL#Notes

- Relative paths resolution

With `style` all relative urls inside are resolved transparently (e.g. `@font-face { src: url('/assets/font.ttf'); }`.
But with blobs, those relative urls are treated as **relative to the blob url** itself (i.e. relative to `blob:http://domain/some-hash`).
So the relative urls will effectively stop working in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Since Firefox doesn't yet support `CSSStyleSheet` and `adoptedStyleSheets`, your technique is very useful for creating self-contained web components prior to the ubiquity of [Constructable Stylesheets](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/387454/166455). See the surrounding [comments](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1520690#c8) in this bug report.